# IPhone App Submission Issues

Tags: ipad, app-store, submission, iphone

Ive submitted my first app and it has been approved. But I have a few issues that i'd like to ask what I should do about.

1. One of my images/icons that I have in my app showed correctly in my distributed binary at my end (running it in debug simulator from xcode) but on the app downloaded from the app store it is not showing at all?
2. IPads cannot see my app in their search of the app store?
3. IOS 4 is needed to run my app. How do i change it so that it can be run on IOS 3 aswell? And if i make it IOS 3 compatible does this mean that it cannot be run in the background at all (i.e. when the close out of my app and go back into it will it restart the entire app)

Also does anyone know whether submitting an update is quicker in the review process than submitting a entirely new app?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Thats a QA issue. The simulator is just that and if you want to be sure that your App runs as you expect on hardware then you need to check it on hardware. There are instances of images that decode on simulator but not on hardware.
2. iPad only runs iOS 3.2 at the mo so if your app runs on 4.0 it wont show up for iPad.
3. See 2 and no you dont have multitasking in 3.2 so you need to make sure your app state persists across atomic launches. You'll need to remove/conditionally compile any 4.0 only API in your App. If thats a problem wait until November-ish.
4. Maybe, depends, probably no. Lead time on update/new submission is around 8 days +/- YMMV.

Comment: 1. Sorry didnt explain myself well, I did test it out deployed to a device and the image is there.

3. If a 3.2 compatible app is run on 4.0 IOS and the application is closed than does it restart when the user clicks on the icon?

Also what is happening in November-ish?

Comment: iOS 4.2 gets released to iPad in November. As to whether a 3.2 linked app gets backgrounded or terminated in iOS 4.0 I dont know.