# IOS3 Compatible App in IOS4 Mutlitasking

Tags: iphone, ios4, multitasking, ios3.0

This is a follow on from [IPhone App Submission Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648530/iphone-app-submission-issues)

If I have a IOS3 compatible app, how does it handle in IOS4 in regards to Multitasking? i.e. When the IOS3 app is closed on an IOS4 phone and than they reopen it, will it restart or is it backgrounded/multitasked and when reloaded taken to where the user just was?

Does anyone have advice on how i should go about this? I need to convert my current IOS4 compatible app back so that it is compatible with IOS3 quickly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile an app using the 4.x SDK but with a deployment target of 3.x, then when running under iOS 4.0, suspend (applicationDidEnterBackground) and sometimes resume (applicationWillEnterForeground:) will be called, depending on what the user or the system did in the meantime; and under iPhone OS 3.x, terminate (applicationWillTerminate ) will be called and your app will be terminated.

See the [iOS App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072) for more details.

Comment: So thats all i need to do? Make sure my sdk is set to 4.x and set my deployment target to 3.x and I will than be IOS3 compatible?

Just to be make sure im certain, this will also mean that it is IPad compatible aswell since it is IOS3 compatible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's all you need to do. BUT, you have to make sure you don't call or access any 4.0-specific classes, constants, or functions. As for iPad compatibility, all 3.x stuff can run on iPad, but unless you code for it, it will be in compatibility mode (ie, just a double-sized iPhone display).

Comment: If you set the deployment target to 3.x, stick to 3.x APIs, and you test it on a 3.x device, then your app should be ok to run on 3.x devices, including the iPad in 1X/2X zoom mode.